# Yii ActiveRecord field only returns default value for recently added column

Tags: activerecord, yii

**Yii 1.1.12:**
When I select an instance of the User model, I get the default value for certain properties/columns. This happens for columns that I have recently added (manually) to the database:

```
$user->locale    // returns null (= default value)
```

If I set a new, different default value in the database (via phpMyAdmin), I will receive that new default value.

Other columns of that table do just fine:

```
$user->email     // returns the correct value
```

I will receive the **correct value** if I run an SQL query:

```
SELECT locale FROM tbl_users WHERE tbl_users.id = :userID LIMIT 1
```

From this I deduce that the database is just fine. The problem must be in the Active Records implementation.

I would expect that Yii's **magic methods** simply find each database column and add them as a (virtual) property to the model. This appears to be happening, but somehow the database-column default value is interjected.

What am I doing wrong?

**Solution:** As Sam suggested, removing **defaultScope()** did the trick. Apparently, a AR-property must be listed in **defaultScope()** to be recognized. Alternatively, **defaultScope()** can be removed in its entirety.

Comment: Could we see the code where you add/update the model?

Comment: Also need model code itself, especially `rules()` method.

Comment: Please see here for code and live example: http://www.essential-strategy.com/ar/bug

Comment: Remove `defaultScope`, no need to list all fields.

Comment: Thanks Sam, removing **defaultScope()** did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleaned up Yii cache after adding deafault values to MySQL?

Comment: No, I have not cleaned up the cache. I have never messed with any Yii cache and a google search did not reveal how this might be accomplished.

Comment: Well, restart Apache, cleanup runtime folder.