# Yii doesn't find model by a given attribute

Tags: model, yii, find

My password is not encrypted. I'm using it for a simple site. Anyway when I tried searching for a model by it's password

```
Yii::log("Password: " . CVarDumper::dumpAsString($this->password),'debug');
$record = Guest::model()->findByAttributes(array('password'=>$this->password));
```

When I log `$this->password` it does show that its initialized but `$record` returns null. However if I find it by its ID it does return something. Also I tried manually injecting the SQL on phpmyadmin it does work.

Sorry, such a newbie here.

Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code, recheck those values, obviously make sure you are looking for the exact same record with id method, and sql method

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip:
I searched for `first_name` attribute with this `Guest::model()->findByAttributes(array('first_name'=>$this->first_name));` and returned me a record. I'm not sure why can't use `password` as the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that 'password' is not listed in defaultScope()

See here: [Yii ActiveRecord field only returns default value for recently added column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550296/yii-activerecord-field-only-returns-default-value-for-recently-added-column)

Could you show your model for Guest?

Comment: Hi I already fixed it but what I did was backup my Guest model and recreate it using Gii. Afterwards, copied the contents from my backedup Guest model then paste it to the new one. Not sure why it fixed it though same code was used.